# Fixed Position Anchor Causes Page to "Stick"

Tags: wordpress, tags, anchor, fixed

I have been really struggling with this issue and will do my best to articulate the problem here.

I have a fixed header on my site and on some pages and anchor tag that takes you to the comments section of the page. When you click the link the page shows nothing and appears to be "stuck" meaning you can not scroll back up. When you look at the code you can see the content is there, but you can't see it.

**I tried to use some of the fixes that add a margin on the anchor itself. None of them work.**

This seems to be a different issue that I can not seem to put my finger on.

If someone wants to take a look at the site (which is currently behind a "Coming Soon" template) I can set up a temporary login and password for you to poke around.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. It's good practice to include example code and steps to reproduce. I don't expect anyone wants to do the work for you.

Comment: Not expecting anyone to do the work for me and I don't appreciate the implication that those were my expectations. I clearly stated it was an unusual case and if anyone wants a login to see the issue in real-time I would be more than happy to provide. I have been coding professionally for 10 years (should I have included that?) and I have never seen this kind of issue. I just want someone to take a look and let me know if it's a conflict in code or something else.

Comment: Listen, I'm not trying to imply anything. I'm just telling you that you're significantly more likely to get an answer if you post a gist, example, or something similar.

Comment: Did you read my original post? It's an issue that I am not familiar with and is not as simple as posting code. I wish it was. Again, I offered to create a login for site if anyone wanted to look at the issue. It appears tho that may not happen here after this exchange. I will seek advice elsewhere.